# Android ImageView no render with Thread.sleep

Tags: android

I have this ImageView in andriod and I need to change the filter when a click is performed so is like this

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        imageView.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
```

The problem is I never see the green color and I can't sync this up with the Thread.sleep

Any ideas? That will help me a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always see a huge red flag when you see `Thread.sleep` in just about anything other than testing code. `Thread.sleep` in your main UI thread would lock the UI which is terrible UX.

There is a better way to do this using the `Handler` class.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       imageView.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
   }
}, 1000);
```

This says run the `Runnable` in 1000 milliseconds.